# Class in Python is not returning a variable

Tags: python, class

I’m a complete newbie to python and wanted to write such a simple script for others to guess my age. I also wanted to count the number of times guessed (self.tries), but the script doesn't count that. Where did I go wrong?

```
class Age:
  def __init__(self, *tries):
    self.tries = tries
    self.my_age = 14

  def guess(self):
    self.tries = 0
    number = int(input('How old I am?- '))
    if number == self.my_age:
        print('')
        print('Congratulations, you guessed it from the 1st time!')
    else:
        if number > self.my_age:
            print(f'\nTry no.: {self.tries}')
            self.tries += 1
            print(f'|-- Incorrect. I am younger than {number} --|')
            repeat = input('Try once again? (Y/N)- ').upper()
            if repeat == 'Y':
                self.guess()
            else:
                pass
        elif number < self.my_age:
            print(f'\nTry no.: {self.tries}')
            self.tries += 1
            print(f'|-- Incorrect. I am older than {number} --|')
            repeat = input('Try once again? (Y/N)- ').upper()
            if repeat == 'Y':
                self.guess()
            else:
                pass
```

```py
x = Age(1)
x.guess()
```

Comment: You could just do `print(x.tries)` after you've called `x.guess()`

Comment: Every time you call `.guess()`, you're setting `self.tries = 0` in the first line of the method definition.

Comment: You define `self.tries` as `1` when you call `Age(1)` but then in `guess()` you set it back to `0`

Answer (score 0):

Declare `tries` variable in `__init__` only, don't initialize it with 0 again in `guess` function. You will get correct count this way :

```
class Age:
    def __init__(self, *tries):
        self.tries = tries
        self.my_age = 14
        self.tries = 1


    def guess(self):
        number = int(input('How old I am?- '))
        if number == self.my_age:
            print('')
            print('Congratulations, you guessed it from the 1st time!')
        else:
            if number > self.my_age:
                print(f'\nTry no.: {self.tries}')
                self.tries += 1
                print(f'|-- Incorrect. I am younger than {number} --|')
                repeat = input('Try once again? (Y/N)- ').upper()
                if repeat == 'Y':
                    self.guess()
                else:
                    pass
            elif number < self.my_age:
                print(f'\nTry no.: {self.tries}')
                self.tries += 1
                print(f'|-- Incorrect. I am older than {number} --|')
                repeat = input('Try once again? (Y/N)- ').upper()
                if repeat == 'Y':
                    self.guess()
                else:
                    pass


x = Age(1)
x.guess()
```

Answer (score 0):

I simplified problem to draw attention to some of the key parts of the solution.  The easiest way do the same thing over and over again in a program is to use a loop.  For this problem you want to keep looping over the user interaction code until either the user guesses correctly or they give up.  While looping, you want to keep track of the number of attempts to customize your messages and to inform the user of their effort.

Example:

```
def guess_my_age(actual_age):
    
    keep_trying = True
    tries = 0

    while keep_trying:

        tries += 1
        print(f"Try number: {tries}")
        
        guessed_age = int(input("How old am I? "))  

        if guessed_age == actual_age:
            if tries == 1:
                print("Congratulations, you guessed my age on your first try!")
            else:
                print(f"Nice, you guessed my age after {tries} tries.")
            keep_trying = False

        else:
            if guessed_age > actual_age:
                print(f"Sorry, I am younger than {guessed_age}.")
            else:
                print(f"Sorry, I am older than {guessed_age}.")

            keep_trying = input('Try again? (Y/N) ').upper() == "Y"


guess_my_age(14)
```